# example using memcache with jpa entitymanager on JGAE?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, datanucleus

any example on using memcache/general cache with jpa entitymanager on JGAE? or the only way to do it is manually put/set memcache on service layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataNucleus docs define adequately how to use the JDO/JPA L2 cache. 
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_1_1/jpa/cache.html
in the case of GAE/J memcache the L2 cache should be "javax.cache".

Comment: do u know i can get working demo sample?  on using @Cachable on datanucleus 1.1.5

Comment: i tried setting datanucleus.cache.level2.type to memcache but it down work.  by the way "soft" is not suitable for clustering environement like GAE right?

Comment: And why would you set it to memcache ? I already said in my first post you set it to "javax.cache" (which is what GAE/J provides). Also if you want to say something "doesn't work" then perhaps providing information about why you say that, otherwise its meaningless

Comment: i tried javax.cache but cannot compile.  I able to compile without problem when use type "soft".

Comment: NO idea what you're talking about. You set a persistence property as some String ... in this case "javax.cache". That has no impact whatsoever on you compiling your code. None. DataNucleus provides commercial support for those who need it.

Comment: DataNucleus, the link is broken.